# Why can't I properly use strings and arrays in my code

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm trying to do an assignment and every time i try to use a string it crashes and because of this line of code in gs_report.c

```
        if (IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_FASTFAIL_AVAILABLE))
        {
            __fastfail(FAST_FAIL_STACK_COOKIE_CHECK_FAILURE);
        }
```

my assignment was to

Write a program that uses:

- an array of string objects to hold the five student names
- an array of five characters to hold the five students’ letter grades
- five arrays of four doubles to hold each student’s set of test scores

The program should allow the user to enter each student’s name and his or her four test scores.

It should then calculate and display each student’s average test score, and a letter grade based on the average.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char names[100][100], grades[5];
    int i,j;
    double scores[5][4], averages[5];

    grades[0] = 'A';
    grades[1] = 'B';
    grades[2] = 'C';
    grades[3] = 'D';
    grades[4] = 'F';

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        printf("enter the name of student %d", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%c", &names[i]);

        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("enter test score number %d: ", j);
            scanf_s("%lf", &scores[i][j]);
        }

        sum += scores[i][j];
        averages[i] = sum / 4;

        if (averages[i] >= 90) 
        {
        grades[i] = 'A';
        }
    
        else if (averages[i] >= 80)
        {
        grades[i] = 'B';
        }

        else if (averages[i] >= 70)
        {
        grades[i] = 'C';
        }

        else if (averages[i] >= 60)
        {
        grades[i] = 'D';
        }

        else
        {
        grades[i] = 'F';
        }

    }


    printf("\n%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", "Student Name", "Average Test Score", "Letter Grade");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%-20s%-20.2lf%-20c\n", names[i], averages[i], grades[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This only occurs when I use %s instead of %c but when I use %c my for loop keeps repeating without any user input.

Comment: The `scanf` format `%c` is for reading a single character. If you want to read a string use `%s`. Is it just a typo, or a brainfart or something?

Comment: On a relate note, the `%s` format expect an argument of type `char *`. The type of `&names[i]` is `char (*)[100]`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefine behavior*. You need either `&names[i][0]` to get a pointer to the first element, or just plain `names[i]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the %c was a typo but trying both of the answers you gave me led to the same error in gs_report.c the error reason is "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF61DE5344D in ASimon7B.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun."

Comment: Build with debug information. Run in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Catch the crash and locate when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: As a hint: After the loop `for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)`, what do you think the value of `j` will be? What do you think `sum += scores[i][j];` will do? Should that assignment be *inside* the loop? Then you don't need an array for `scores`.

Comment: Prefer localized variables.  This would highlight the issue that @Someprogrammerdude just mentioned.

Comment: Do you assign values to `grades[]` when you just overwrite them again the loop?

Comment: @AllanWind the error occurs as soon as i type in a string for `names[i]` . i tried using localized variables but i continue to get the same error and i don't assign any values to `grades[]`

Comment: @aiden, `scanf_s("%c", &names[i]);` is missing an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because you didn't minimize the scope of your loop variable `j` you don't notice that:

   ```
            sum += scores[i][j];
   ```

   is after the loop at which point `j=5` so it result in a out of bound access of `scores`. This result in undefined behavior.
2. `scanf()`: You use the directive `%c` which is used to read a character but you want to use `%s` to read a word.  Also, you want to use the matching `names[i]` (or `&names[i][0]`) so it's the correct `char *` type.
3. (Not fixed) If your student names contain space then you want to read a line instead of a word.  You can do that with the format directive `"%" str(NAME_LEN) "[^\n]"` but this will leave the `\n` in the input buffer so you also have to change the directive for reading scores to ignore leading white space with `" %lf"` (leading space is significant).  Alternative, use `fgets()` to read a line and remove the `\n' from the resulting name read.

   I switched to `scanf()` here as `scanf_s()` is Microsoft specific I believe.  With `scanf()` we want to always use maximum field width to avoid buffer overflows.
4. (Not fixed) always check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data.
5. You hard-code magic numbers all over the place.  Use symbolic constants instead.  This allows you to easily change the number of students from 5 to, say, 2 for testing.
6. You assign assign values to `grades` initially then overwrite it in the loop so just leave it uninitialized (or zero initialize it if you prefer).
7. Changed the prompt to be consistent with the name prompt.
8. (Not fixed) I would use a macro to generate the two related format strings:

   ```
   #define FORMAT(average,grade) "%-20s%-20" average "%-20" grade "\n"
   ```

   so you write the header with `FORMAT("s", "s")` and data rows with `FORMAT(".2lf", "c")`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SCORES 4
#define NAME_LEN 99
#define STUDENTS 2
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int main(void) {
    char names[STUDENTS][NAME_LEN+1];
    char grades[STUDENTS];
    double averages[STUDENTS];
    double scores[STUDENTS][SCORES];
    for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
        printf("enter the name of student %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %" str(NAME_LEN) "[^\n]", names[i]);
        double sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < SCORES; j++) {
            printf("enter test score number %d: ", j + 1);
            scanf(" %lf", &scores[i][j]);
            sum += scores[i][j];
        }
        averages[i] = sum / SCORES;
        if (averages[i] >= 90)
            grades[i] = 'A';
        else if (averages[i] >= 80)
            grades[i] = 'B';
        else if (averages[i] >= 70)
            grades[i] = 'C';
        else if (averages[i] >= 60)
            grades[i] = 'D';
        else
            grades[i] = 'F';
    }
    printf(
        "\n"
        "%-20s%-20s%-20s\n"
        "------------------------------------------------------------\n",
        "Student Name",
        "Average Test Score",
        "Letter Grade"
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++)
        printf("%-20s%-20.2lf%-20c\n", names[i], averages[i], grades[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

and example run:

```
enter the name of student 1: bob
enter test score number 1: 70
enter test score number 2: 70
enter test score number 3: 70 
enter test score number 4: 70
enter the name of student 2: jane
enter test score number 1: 80
enter test score number 2: 80
enter test score number 3: 80
enter test score number 4: 80

Student Name        Average Test Score  Letter Grade
------------------------------------------------------------
bob                 70.00               C                   
jane                80.00               B
```

Comment: A couple of good exercises for you would be to introduce a `struct` for student that groups the name and scores.  Make a function that calculates the average for a student instead of storing the redundant information.  Same for grade.  In the `grade()` function use an array of a structs that maps a a minimum score to a grade.  Then the conversion from score is a loop with a return instead of the 5-way `if` statement, and its easy data change if the curve changes.